# Chrome Request Blocking (Experimental Feature) - how to unblock?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am using an experimental feature in Chrome called "Request Blocking" to simulate the behavior of an ad blocker which is blocking our New Relic script.

After the feature is enabled:

[image: New menu option to block the URL]

and after refreshing:

[image: chrome dev tools - resource blocked - yay!]

but when I access the menu again, the only Request Blocking option is:

[image: no unblock option]

Obviously this feature is experimental and may be incomplete (maybe it's just not coded yet!). Has anyone uncovered a way to un-block resources when using the Request Blocking experimental feature?

I uncovered the feature from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39475590/1861459).

---

Solution: resetting the browser as the accepted answer suggests worked, but I was able to keep my settings and only "undo" the experiment's changes by disabling the experiment and restarting Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When in doubt, try resetting Chrome before using an experiment.

I was seeing similar problems when I first enabled the experiment, but after resetting Chrome, there's now a blue icon next to the **Offline** checkbox, and a **Request Blocking** tab in the Drawer. Clicking the blue icon opens the tab.

[image: request blocking UI]

Comment: Resetting Chrome worked but should be considered a nuclear option. I was able to disable the experiment, restart the browser and see that the request was no longer blocked.