# How to block a URL in Firefox's network monitor

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools, network-monitoring

I'm trying to block a specific script in firefox from loading locally.

Two days ago, it worked from the [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_list#Filtering_requests) as shown here.

However, I've been struggling to get it to work today, deleted firefox, cleaned user profile, everything, but I can't just see the `Block URL`:
[image]

Am I missing something? Has someone faced the same issue?

`Firefox: 67, Mac OS: 10.14.3`.

Ps:

> I could use third-party tools, which I have to manually select or input
>   a link to block some script ( I have not found any working for me)
>
> I use chrome every day, and it can be done in chrome as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863094/how-to-block-a-url-in-chromes-developer-tools-network-monitor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is a new feature in Firefox 68, which is currently in beta testing.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/68
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1151368

To do that in v67.x (the current version) and previous versions, I would use [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) or [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) for that.

Comment: Thank you. I"ll look into the add-ons and try using the latest version. It feels strange because I used it on 67 and it just disappeared.