# Is it possible to ask Chrome to intentionally unable to load a specific JavaScript URL?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I want to debug a page, which looks like this in its `<head>` section:

I want to debug the case when the `https://example.com/some-js-from-external-site.js` is unable to load without making any changes to the page. Is it possible to use Chrome Dev Tools to "simulate" that the URL returns a 404 or something?

Thanks,

Comment: If it’s a unique domain (from other page resources), a host entry will work in a pinch.

Comment: but that would need to edit the host file, and will be affected by cache settings

Comment: Try [blocking the request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45784247). Otherwise use an external tool like Fiddler, Charles, and so on.