# Block all requests(for current website) using chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How could I block all requests using chrome DevTools?

I already know:

- Block the network request that has been emitted: [How to block a URL in Chrome's developer tools network monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863094/how-to-block-a-url-in-chromes-developer-tools-network-monitor)

But I want to block the request that doesn't happen.
Or is it possible to block all requests?

E.G.:
In the following request, `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/...` appears for the first time, but I don't want this request to be sent out (we are limited to the Fetch/XHR type), so I couldn't block this request before (there is a special case here is the above request is the same domain name as this request, so it can be resolved through the block domain name, but there was no request for the same domain name before in my scenario).

[image: scene example]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and explain what requests are you talking about ?

Comment: @PathikritDas Hi, I just added an example to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, it's hidden in the options.

[image: The example]